# Termcal calendar not centered

Tags: horizontal-alignment, termcal

For some reason, my termcal calendar is not being properly centered by being placed within a center environment. The MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{termcal}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{calendar}{9/30/2013}{11}
\setlength{\calboxdepth}{.3in}
\setlength{\calwidth}{0.8\textwidth} 
% week description
\skipday
\calday[Tuesday]{\classday}
\skipday
\calday[Thursday]{\classday}
\skipday\skipday\skipday
\end{calendar}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

but this doesn't center my calendar, as shown here [image: screenshot]

Comment: Please make your example start `\documentclass` and end `\end{document}` so the problem may be reproduced. (that's what the `W` in `MWE` means) that said, try `\mbox{}\begin{calendar}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `termcal` package uses a `longtable`  to typeset the calendar and hard codes the calendar to be left justified.  You can patch the relevant part of the `calendar` environment using `etoolbox` to get what you need:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{termcal}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\endcalendar}{[l]}{[c]}{}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{calendar}{9/30/2013}{11}

\setlength{\calboxdepth}{.3in}
\setlength{\calwidth}{0.8\textwidth} 
% week description
\skipday
\calday[Tuesday]{\classday}
\skipday
\calday[Thursday]{\classday}
\skipday\skipday\skipday
\end{calendar}
\end{document}
```

Another option would be to redefine the `calendar` environment to admit one optional argument allowing to specify the desired alignment for the calendar; here's such a possible redefinition, taking `c` (centered) as the default value for the alignment; the example illustrates the default and also shows the use of `l` (left justified) and `r` (right justified):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{termcal}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{calendar}[3][c]%
 {%
   \setcounter{ca@numwks}{#3}
   \setdate{#2}
   \setcounter{ca@dpw}{0}
   \setcounter{classnum}{1}
   \gdef\calalign{#1}
 }
  {
   \ifca@chead\ca@doweeks{\the\ca@colhead\endhead\hline\hline}\fi
   \setcounter{ca@wknum}{0}
   \whiledo{\value{ca@wknum}<\value{ca@numwks}}%
            {\stepcounter{ca@wknum}%
             \addtotoks{\ca@doweeks}{\the\ca@doaweek\\\hline}}
   \ca@boxwidth=\calwidth
   \divide\ca@boxwidth by \c@ca@dpw\relax
   \advance\ca@boxwidth by -2\tabcolsep\relax
   \setlength\@tempdima\arrayrulewidth\relax
   \multiply\@tempdima\c@ca@dpw\relax
   \advance\@tempdima\arrayrulewidth\relax
   \divide\@tempdima\c@ca@dpw\relax
   \advance\ca@boxwidth by -\@tempdima\relax
   \begin{longtable}[\calalign]
   {|*{\theca@dpw}{p{\ca@boxwidth}|}@{}}%
      \hline
      \the\ca@doweeks
    \end{longtable}
   }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{calendar}{9/30/2013}{2}
\setlength{\calboxdepth}{.3in}
\setlength{\calwidth}{0.5\textwidth} 
% week description
\skipday
\calday[Tuesday]{\classday}
\end{calendar}

\begin{calendar}[l]{9/30/2013}{2}
\setlength{\calboxdepth}{.3in}
\setlength{\calwidth}{0.5\textwidth} 
% week description
\skipday
\calday[Tuesday]{\classday}
\end{calendar}

\begin{calendar}[r]{9/30/2013}{2}
\setlength{\calboxdepth}{.3in}
\setlength{\calwidth}{0.5\textwidth} 
% week description
\skipday
\calday[Tuesday]{\classday}
\end{calendar}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, that worked even without the center environment.

Comment: -1 for blaming `longtable` :-)

Comment: I made an edit adding a redefinition of calendar so as to admit an optional argument to specify the desired alignment. I hope it's OK, but, of course, feel free to roll it back if you don't like it :-)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Since the calendar is usually the kind of thing you use only once per document, it's not clear there's a great advantage to doing this.  It would probably be simpler to make a wrapper for the patch command.

Comment: @AlanMunn well, yes, the idea was to illustrate that, in my opinion, allowing to specify the alignment should have been the original definition. I was just trying to show to beginners how this can be done. Anyway, feel free to roll back the edit.